# Cloud-init Always Adding Ubuntu User?

Tags: server, cloud-init

I am using Packer and cloud-init to create templates for proxmox. I am so lost and annoyed. Every time I create a template my user is created with a uid and gid 1000 then right after it the Ubuntu user is created with a uid of 1001 and gid 1002. I can’t find this happening to anyone any where. I read the documentation and it says that if a user is defined the Ubuntu user won’t be created. Am I wrong I’ve so many different cloud-configs I can’t count. To make it more annoying every time I try to remove the Ubuntu user with automation after the template is created the next boot the Ubuntu user is right back in there. I am at such a loss. Have stumbled upon a weird bug and I doing something wrong? I’ve gone through the logs like crazy and all it says is the ubuntu user is created it gives no mention as to why.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: us
 ssh:
   install-server: true
   allow-pw: true
   disable_root: true
   ssh_quiet_keygen: true
   allow_public_ssh_keys: true
packages:
  - qemu-guest-agent
  - sudo
storage:
  layout:
    name: direct
  swap:
    size: 0
user-data:
  package_upgrade: false
  timezone: (user timezone)
  users:
    - name: (user)
      groups: [adm, sudo]
      lock-passwd: false
      sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
      shell: /bin/bash
      passwd:(user password)
      ssh_authorized_keys:
        - (user ssh key)
```

Comment: The behavior you describe does indeed seem contrary to https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html. Therefore a bug. Please see https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/bugs.html for how to report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Also seeing this issue on 22.04.2 iso and packer proxmox v1.1.3.

Ended up just adding an ansible playbook for it to run after as a workaround, sharing here

```
- name: Remove the user 'ubuntu'
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: ubuntu
    state: absent
    remove: yes #delete dirs

- name: Remove sudo access for deleted 'ubnt' user
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users
    state: absent
    search_string: 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'
    validate: 'visudo -cf %s'


- name: Remove left over config for deleted 'ubnt' user
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users
    state: absent
    search_string: '# User rules for ubuntu'
    validate: 'visudo -cf %s'
```